# Getting path of file on local machine without uploading in PHP

Tags: php, html, php-5.3, php-5.4

I have an html form with input as file.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form hideit2">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info" />
</form>
```

I just want to browse the file and get its full path on users system without uploading it to the server.

```
Eg:- $myvariable = 'C:/user/username/desktop/filename';
```

Is this possible? Let me know the way.

Comment: Nope..you cannot get local machine path from server

Comment: What do you mean by "browse the file"? How can a program "browse" anything?

Comment: for what purpose? a bit of background might help us guide you better.

Comment: @DevDonkey I am processing a video after uploading it to my localhost/upload folder. Since i have the video on my desktop so i dont want to unnecessarily copy(or upload) it to another folder on localhost of my PC. I want to use the video straight from desktop folder.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Can't you imagine the security breach that would imply? That would be like giving full control of your local machine to the server hosting the page.